# AWS S3 image in SwiftUI app causes extreme lag?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, url, swiftui

so in my app, I'm fetching some S3 images from the S3 URL and rendering them in my SwiftUI app. The URL looks something like and 'test-image-name' is about 5 MB:

```
https://s3-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/test-image-name
```

Inside of my SwiftUI app, the image is rendered like this:

```
Image(systemName: "camera")
    .data(url: URL(string: "https://s3-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/test-image-name")!)
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFill()
    .maxHeight(150)
    .clipped()
    .onAppear() {
        print("Image: \(URL(string: "https://s3-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/test-image-name")!)")
    }
```

or this way:

```
Image(systemName: "camera")
    .data(url: URL(string: "https://s3-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/test-image-name")!)
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFill()
    .maxHeight(260)
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    .clipped()
```

For some reason, when I don't have these Image blocks in the SwiftUI code, the app runs smoothly but as soon as these Image blocks are included in the code (regardless of whether they are presented or not in the views on the screen), there is extreme lag where it tags a minute plus to register touches/drags. Throughout the app, I have other images with domain that don't cause any lag whatsoever:

```
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I was thinking maybe the S3 fetch time is long, and in SwiftUI apps state changes cause re-renders all the time, but I'm not sure.

Not sure how to fix this, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What does your data modifier do? Where does it come from?